# String variable name to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, string, object, undefined

I have two variables like this:

```
var test = {"1":"test","2":"test2"};
var isdefined = "test.1"
```

How can I check isdefined variable is not 'undefined'?

Thanks!

Comment: typeof isdefined === "undefined"

Comment: `if(isdefined !== undefined)`

Comment: @RabNawaz looking undefined without typeof is not better way. We can overwrite it. `var undefined = true;`.

Comment: If you are trying to test that a variable with the name of `test.1` exists and is not `undefined` you are going to have issues as variables names cannot have a period between characters.

Comment: `var isdefined = "test.1";`. Why are you using double quotes? Beside this, `test.1` generates a "unexpected number exception". Maybe you meant this expression insted: `var undefined = test[1];`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to test if `1` exists in `test`? In that case, you could do

```
test.hasOwnProperty('1')
```

Comment: Is posible without spliting the string?

Comment: Sadly in your case No. Since you are sending both the object and the propery separated by '.'

Answer (score 1):

The answer of your question is No and Yes,

No, because if your object property starts with a number or it is a number you cannot access it using objectName.12 it is a rule you cannot change and in your case it is a number

on the other hand it is Yes, if your object defined properly you can do it please check the below code block;

```
var test = {"1":"test","_2":"test2"};
var isdefined = "test._2";
alert(eval(isdefined)); // will return test2
alert(eval("test.1"));  // throws exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `undefined` evaluates to `false`, so you can simply do:

```
if ( isdefined ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Note, though, if it is `null`, `0`, `''`, `false`, it will also evaluate to `false`. If that's not an issue for you, this is the way to go.